# R: Why this doesn't work?, matrix, rounding error?

Tags: r, matrix

Why this works:

```
ncota <- 1
nslope <- 29
resul <- matrix(rep(0,ncota*nslope*4),ncota*nslope,4)
```

But this doesn't?

```
ncota <- 1
sini <- 0.1; sfin <- 1.5; spaso <- 0.05; nslope <- 1+((sfin-sini)/spaso)
resul <- matrix(rep(0,ncota*nslope*4),ncota*nslope,4)
```

I guess the problem is that the division gives a noninteger number.
How can I get the second one work?
I need to create a zero matrix with its size calculated from a equation calculation.

cheers

Comment: @Juan: it's impolite to cross post across several lists (i.e. stackoverflow and R-help).

Comment: Hi.  I thought they where different sites. I asked on both because I didn't know who is gonna reply  and where.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If all you have to do is create a matrix of zeroes, you don't need to supply the correct number of zeroes, just supply one and let R recycle it to the required length:

```
matrix(0, ncota*nslope, 4)
```

The reason the second one fails is that `ncota * nslope * 4` is not exactly 116:

```
> (ncota * nslope * 4) == 116
[1] FALSE
> all.equal(ncota * nslope * 4, 116)
[1] TRUE
```

`all.equal` shows that these are equal **if** you allow for the floating point error.

`?rep` includes the following:

```
 Non-integer values of ‘times’ will be truncated towards zero.  If
 ‘times’ is a computed quantity it is prudent to add a small fuzz.
```

and if we do as it says and add a small fuzz, `rep` does give the desired number of 0s:

```
> length(rep(0, times = ncota*nslope*4 + 0.00000001))
[1] 116
```

As noted by Hadley (in the comments), this fuzz can be easily added using the `zapsmall` function:

```
> length(rep(0, times = zapsmall(ncota*nslope*4)))
[1] 116
```

Comment: Awesome answer; very complete!

Comment: Another useful function in this circumstance is `zapsmall`

Comment: Thanks Hadley, had forgotten about that function. I've added a note on this to my answer.

Comment: @user425895: R relies on floating point arithmetic. See the R FAQ entry 7.31 for further details: http://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-doesn_0027t-R-think-these-numbers-are-equal_003f

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `rep`.  This works just fine:

```
resul <- matrix(0,ncota*nslope,4)
```